# Problem with interrupts and 4x encoders on Nano 33 BLE

Tags: rotary-encoder, arduino-nano-ble

I have a [Pololu 4x encoder](https://www.pololu.com/product/4761) and am trying to write some code to make it work on my Nano 33 BLE. (Interestingly enough, the issue preventing some pre-existing libraries from working for me is the same issue that I'm about to describe here...)

When I turn the motor shaft clockwise, these are the signals that I get (first bit in each pair is channel A, second bit channel B):

`11 -> 10 -> 11 -> 10 -> 11 -> 10`

Note how channel A's value never changes, and B's value toggles back and forth.

Likewise, for the counterclockwise direction:

`01 -> 11 -> 01 -> 11 -> 01 -> 11`

This is of course wrong, as [the channels' values should be something like `00 -> 10 -> 11 -> 01 -> 00` as the shaft turns](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-w-6mSdd0s5A/UHULV8RjH_I/AAAAAAAAAok/-FBhle0uW8o/s400/ROTARY-state.png). As a matter of fact, that is exactly what I get when I run the *exact same code* on a regular Arduino Nano.

Does anyone know what's going on? Here's my code. AFAIK I'm not using interrupts incorrectly or anything, at least for the regular Nano.

```
#define PIN_A 2
#define PIN_B 3

volatile int val = 0;
volatile bool newVal = true;

void encoder() {
  int a = digitalRead(PIN_A);
  int b = digitalRead(PIN_B);
  val = ((a << 1) | b);
  newVal = true;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);

  pinMode(PIN_A, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(PIN_A), encoder, CHANGE);

  pinMode(PIN_B, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(PIN_B), encoder, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  if (newVal) {
    Serial.print(bool(val & 0b10));
    Serial.print(bool(val & 0b01));
    Serial.println();
    newVal = false;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** After taking a look at the following diagram, it appears that the erroneous encoder patterns match those in which only rising edges are detected. So for some reason, `attachInterrupt()` is acting as if the `CHANGE` argument were `RISING` instead for the Nano BLE.

[image]

Comment: Probably not the source of your issue, but change val from a volatile int to a volatile byte.  You only need one byte and with int you're technically doing a multi-byte read of a volatile variable with all that entails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the cause of the issue was that `attachInterrupt()`'s implementation in the nRF528x Mbed core does not properly support rising/falling edge detection as required for mode `CHANGE`. I've [opened a pull request](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-nRF528x-mbedos/pull/69) implementing the changes required and tested them with my encoder, and I can confirm that everything works properly now.

If you'd like to test the updated core yourself, you can follow the installation instructions from the repo's [`README`](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-nRF528x-mbedos) or from this very well-written [forum post](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=634250.msg4297961#msg4297961).

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to use a single interrupt for the encoder.  BLE has a faster processor and your code is not frame-based so that just might affect it also.  This code doesn't do exactly what your code did but it will use val to track position as a number.
It can also be made a bit finer using CHANGE instead of RISING, but for debugging bare bones means less that can go wrong.

```
#define PIN_A 2
#define PIN_B 3

volatile int val = 0;
int oldVal;
//volatile bool newVal = true;

void encoder() {
  if(digitalRead(PIN_B)) ++val;
  else --val;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);

  pinMode(PIN_A, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(PIN_B, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(PIN_A), encoder, RISING);
}

void loop() {
  if (val != oldVal) {
    oldVal = val;
    Serial.println(oldVal);
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE.  Please don't post multiple answers to the same question.  Just edit the information into your original answer.

Comment: Please evaluate answers as answers without bias for who posted them.

Comment: I'm not bothered by who posts the answers, but SE is a Q&A site, rather than the forums you might be used to.  There is rarely any need for anyone to post more than one answer to a given question.  You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [How do I write a good answer?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).